# How to convert json to Excel file?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to convert the following link to Excel using Python language so that it stores information about the country and the capital and their code in an Excel file
Can you please guide me?

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Comment: What have you tried already, what does your expected output look like (e.g. how do you intend to tread list fields)? Which part are you stuck at?

Comment: I recommend the following modules:- bs4, requests, openpyxl

Comment: You can use requests for HTML requests and beautifulsoup for parsing its content or you may try a python wrapper already implemented for this API: https://github.com/SteinRobert/python-restcountries .. try your shot and let us know what's blocking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use pandas to read the JSON from the URL that you have mentioned and save it to an excel file. Here's the code for it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Loading the JSON from the URL to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_json('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')

# Selecting the columns for the country name, capital, and the country code (as mentioned in the question)
df = df[["name", "capital", "alpha2Code"]]

# Saving the data frame into an excel file named 'restcountries.xlsx', but feel free to change the name
df.to_excel('restcountries.xlsx')
```

However, there will be an issue with reading nested fields (if you want to read them in the future). For example, the fields named `borders` and `currencies` in your dataset are lists. So, you might need some post-processing after you load it.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, but I had a question for you. When I use the following link instead of the link above, I get into trouble. Can you help me?

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=94e6cc601757d2f2fbdea1a57d9ac55a&units=metric

Comment: The new link that you have sent has an API that is returning a non-series value. Therefore, you've got to manually do a `GET` request using the requests library and load the data into a dictionary `raw_dict = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=94e6cc601757d2f2fbdea1a57d9ac55a&units=metric').json()`. Then, put it to a list using `el = []` and `el.append(raw_dict)`. After that, create a pandas data frame from that list using `df = pd.DataFrame(el)`. After that, just save the data frame into an excel file as mentioned in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Pandas library will come to rescue here, though extracting your nested json is more of a python skills. You can follow the following to simply extract desired columns:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';

#Load json to a dataframe
df = pd.read_json(url); 

# Create DF with Country, capital and code fields. You can use df.head() to see how your data looks in table format and columns name.
df_new = df[['name', 'capital', 'alpha2Code', 'alpha3Code']].copy()

#Use pandas ExcelWriter to write the desired DataFrame to xlsx file. 
with pd.ExcelWriter('country_names.xlsx') as writer:
    df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Country List")
```

[Sample Data from the generated Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1BQX.png)

Full info on ExcelWriter module can be read at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

You will need to play around to change the columns names and clean up the data (especially the nested objects) and these should be just a search away.

Comment: Thank you, but I had a question for you. When I use the following link instead of the link above, I get into trouble. Can you help me?

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=94e6cc601757d2f2fbdea1a57d9ac55a&units=metric